# getting attribute values from selected options in multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, multi-select

I have a multi select element in jQuery.

Here is an example.

```
<select multiple id="multiple">
    <option value="1" type="Alice">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" type="Bob">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

I know I can get all the values that are selected by doing `$("#multiple").val();`

How can I also get the type attributes of the selected options?

Comment: With HTML5 you can use `.selectedOptions`; it's a collection of `Option` elements from which you can get the attribute values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need uses a pseudo `option:selected` and look every option selected:

```
$('#multiple').change(function(){
    var $value =$('option:selected',this).attr('type');
    console.log($value);
});
```

Or using the `.each()` like:

```
$('#multiple option:selected').each(function(){
    var $value =$(this).attr('type');
    console.log($value);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gg38k/3/)

[DEMO With .each()](http://jsfiddle.net/gg38k/4/)

Comment: would upvote this one but the OP asked about how to get the type attribute from the selected elements not the value...

Comment: that still only gives me the value attribute. I want the type attribute.

Comment: Works fine, only problem I see is that when selecting through shift button instead of click, it doesn't work fine

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#multiple", function(){
    var ids = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('type');    
    }).get();
    console.log(ids);
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LFMG7/2/

Comment: The question is about *multiple* select box, i.e. more than element can be selected.

Comment: Yep, that looks better :) though, using a delegated event handler on document doesn't seem like the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest is to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var types = $('#multiple > option:selected').map(function() {
    return this.getAttribute('type');
}).get();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/leveboto/1/watch?html,js,console)

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = document.getElementById('multiple'), a = [], i;
for(i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    if(t[i].selected) a.push(t[i].getAttribute('type'));
}
// tested on IE8+, Chrome (Windows & Linux), Safari, Firefox (Windows & Linux), Opera
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg38k/5/)

Comment: This will not select *all* selected options in one go.

Comment: @Jack Have you checked the provided fiddle?

Comment: Are you trying to make it seem like you had this answer all along? ;-) in any case, are you sure that subscripting the `<select>` element works reliably on all browsers?

Comment: @Jack Well, you may see all the edits :). On the other hand, I'd be glad to know if my answer has a cross-browser issue.

Comment: My point was that you updated your answer *after* my comment; subscripting the select element directly requires the HTML5 interfaces, so not all browsers will have support for this.

Comment: @Jack Of course I've got your point :). Well, I just tested the snippet on six browsers and it works.

Comment: Yeah, but they're all recent browsers; don't expect this to work on IE8 though (yes, I know, it's "ancient" and all).

Comment: @Jack Are you kidding me? :) Just to let you know, I just tested the snippet on IE 8.0.6001 and it works. Of course it works :)

Comment: Well, that comes as a surprise to me because the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#item()) mentions that it's an HTML5 thingie and I didn't have a Windows machine to test on, so thanks for testing that :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var myList = array();
$('#multiple option:selected').each(function(){
    myList.push({"val":$(this).val(), "type":$(this).attr("type")});
});
```

Comment: There's no jQuery function called `.attrib()`.